# Why is pushing to an array not waiting for asynchronous task to complete despite being in .then() statement?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Forgive/please correct any misuse of vocabulary: I am retrieving data from a CORS request, and looping through the results, pushing an object to an array with each iteration. I am able to see the array growing, but as soon as the `$.get()` request is completed, it seems that my array is empty again.

My guess was that the `$.get()` command was running asynchronously, and the second `console.log()` command was simply executing before the `get` had completed. However, I have placed the `console.log()` inside a `.then()` command and am still getting the same issue. Anyone know what is happening here, and how to fix it?

```
Bike = function(dateStolen, frameColors, frameModel, id, imageUrl, manufacturer, serial, location, title, year){
  this.dateStolen = dateStolen;
  this.frameColors = frameColors;
  this.frameModel = frameModel;
  this.id = id;
  this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
  this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
  this.serial = serial;
  this.location = location;
  this.title = title;
  this.year = year;
};

Bike.prototype.addStolenBikesToArray = function(allBikes){
  $.get("https://bikeindex.org:443/api/v3/search?page=1&per_page=25&location=IP&distance=10&stolenness=stolen")
  .then(function(response){
    response.bikes.forEach(function(bike){
      var currentBike = new Bike(bike.date_stolen, bike.frame_colors, bike.frame_model, bike.id, bike.thumb, bike.manufacturer_name, bike.serial, bike.stolen_location, bike.title, bike.year);
      allBikes.push(currentBike);
      // this displays an ever-growing array of bike objects
      console.log(allBikes);
    })
  })
  // this displays an empty array
  .then(console.log(allBikes));
};

Bike.prototype.setColor = function (userName){
  this.userName = userName;
};

exports.bikeModule = Bike;
```

And then my interface file:

```
var Bike = require("./../js/stolenBikes.js").bikeModule;

var determineMostStolenManufacturer = function(bikeArray){
  var manufacturerArray = getArrayOfManufacturers(bikeArray);
  console.log(manufacturerArray);
};

var getArrayOfManufacturers = function(bikeArray){
  var manufacturerArray = [];
  bikeArray.forEach(function(bike){
    manufacturerArray.push(bike.manufacturer);
  });
  return manufacturerArray;
};

$(function(){
  var currentBike = new Bike();
  var allBikes = [];
  currentBike.addStolenBikesToArray(allBikes);
});
```

[Link to my github repo if needed](https://github.com/Atticus29/bike-registration)

Comment: `.then` expects a function as an argument ... not the result of calling a function ... `consoloe.log(blah)` calls console.log, the result of which is `undefined` - this is what is being passed to `.then` - which ignores it, as `.then` ignores non-function arguments

Comment: Tried to wrap that in a function? 'console.log(allBikes)'

Comment: Whenever you have `foo(bar())`, `bar` is executed **first** and its result is passed to `foo`. That means `console.log(allBikes)` is executed, it returns `undefined` which is passed to `.then`. However, `.then` expects a function that can be called once the promise is resolved. So instead of `.then(console.log(allBikes));` you want `.then(() => console.log(allBikes));`.

Comment: Thanks, guys. That fixed it.